# Storing a list returned from a sql query in a model within MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have the code below which returns a list of approximately 2000 items of data. I want to return this into a `model` and pass it back to the `view`.

```
var clientData = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Firm == firm).ToList();
List<ClientEmployees> clientEmployees = new List<ClientEmployees>();

foreach(var client in clientData)
{
      //store in the in the clientEmployees list              
}
```

However i really do not want to go through 1000's of lines of data to store them into the list. I would need to manipulate this data later on, that's why i thought it would be good to use the `model` which i could later manipulate. Any ideas of doing this better?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the foreach loop?

Comment: Have you tried this code clientEmployees.AddRange(clientData).

Comment: Within the foreach loop i wanted to add client to the clientEmployees List. clientEmployee.AddRange() still needs a type of ClientEmployees to be added. So it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there aren't a bunch of fields you could just select the List

```
var clientEmployees = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Firm == firm)
                        .Select(a => new ClientEmployees {
                            Id = a.Id,
                            Name = a.Name,
                            etc..
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

if there are a lot of fields it might be worth looking into AutoMapper or something similar.

.Select also can take a Func<> so you could do something like this in your viewmodel

```
public class ClientEmployees
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static Func<Client, ClientEmployees> FromEntity = item => new ClientEmployees()
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Name = item.Name,
        //map all fields
    };
}
```

then when you select from the db context you just use.

```
var clientEmployees = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Firm == firm)
                    .Select(ClientEmployees.FromEntity)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This allows me to return my data type of ClientEmployees as a list without the use for a foreach loop. I guess this improves performance as i now do not need to iterate. Am i right in thinking this @JamieD77?

Comment: @WobotCode Its still iterating over the collection (how else would you expect the values to be populated)

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  The List contains links to the original datatable so you aren't copying the data and using more memory.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "Enter Your connection strin gHere";
            string SQL = "Enter your SQL Here";

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connStr);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            string firm  = "abc";

            List<DataRow> clientData = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("firm") == firm).ToList();


        }
    }

}
```